# How to seed models with polymorphic one to one relationship in mirage js?

Tags: javascript, ember-cli-mirage, mirage, miragejs

this is just an example, I understand that you would normally have multiple comments, but for the sake of this example, lets assume that we have

following models:

```
 models: {
    blogPost: Model.extend({
      comment: belongsTo(),
    }),

    picture: Model.extend({
      comment: belongsTo(),
    }),

    comment: Model.extend({
      commentable: belongsTo({ polymorphic: true }),
    }),
  },
```

and following factories:

```
  factories: {
    blogPost: Factory.extend({
      title: "Whatever",
      withComment: trait({
        comment: association(),
      }),
  }),
```

Now when trying to seed server with:

```
seeds(server) {
  server.create("blogPost", "withComment");
}
```

It does seed it but when checking `console.log(server.db.dump());` the commentable is null... `commentableId: null`.

[image]

Why?

**EDIT:**

This is a tricky one. I changed

```
comment: Model.extend({
  commentable: belongsTo({ polymorphic: true }),
}),
```

to:

```
comment: Model.extend({
  blogPost: belongsTo({ polymorphic: true }),
}),
```

just to see if `commentable` part is causing the issue. This time I got a different error:
`Mirage: You're using the association() helper on your comment factory for blogPost, which is a polymorphic relationship. This is not currently supported."`

So, it is currently not possible to use `association()` on polymorphic relationship. I wish this was announced in documentation...

Still, I cannot find a way to seed it even without shorthand `association()`.

Comment: This is weird, I think there might be a bug. Need to investigate this one - sorry you ran into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
import { Server, Model, Factory, belongsTo, trait, association, RestSerializer } from "miragejs"

export default new Server({
  serializers: {
    blogPost: RestSerializer.extend({
      include: ['comment']
    }),
  },

  models: {
    blogPost: Model.extend({
      comment: belongsTo(),
    }),

    picture: Model.extend({
      comment: belongsTo(),
    }),

    comment: Model.extend({
      commentable: belongsTo({ polymorphic: true }),
    }),
  },
  
  factories: {
    blogPost: Factory.extend({
      title: "Whatever",
      withComment: trait({
        afterCreate(blogPost, server) {
          server.create('comment', {
            commentable: blogPost
          });
        }
      }),
    })
  },

  seeds(server) {
    server.create("blog-post", "withComment");
    console.log(server.db.dump())
  },
  
  routes() {
    this.resource('blog-post')
  }

})
```

And here's the working REPL: http://miragejs.com/repl/v1/144

If you click the Database tab then click Comments, you should see the polymorphic ID referencing `blog-post:1`.

You can also send a GET to `/blog-posts` and you should see that the comment is included, or send a GET to `/comments` and see the polymorphic `commentable` included.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error:

> You're using the association() helper on your comment factory for blogPost, which is a polymorphic relationship. This is not currently supported."

was resolved for me in this way:
// mirage/factories/comment.js

Before:

```
import { association, Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
  blogPost: association()
```

After:

```
import { association, Factory, trait } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
  blogPost: trait({
    receiver: 'blogPost',
    blogPost: association()
  }),
```